# Usage of WorkspaceJob

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse plugin which has some performance issues. Looking into the progress view sometimes there are multiple jobs waiting and from the code most of it's arhitecture is based on classes which extend `WorkspaceJobs` mixed with `Guava EventBus` events. The current solution involves also nested jobs...

I read the documentation, I understand their purpose, but I don't get it why would I use a workspace job when I could run `syncexec/asyncexec` from methods which get triggered when an event is sent on the bus?

For example instead of creating 3 jobs which wait one for another, I could create an event which triggers what would have executed `Job 1`, then when the method is finished, it would have sent a different event type which will trigger a method that does what `Job 2` would have done and so on...

So instead of:

```
WorkspaceJob Job1 = new WorkspaceJob("Job1");
Job1.schedule();
WorkspaceJob Job2 = new WorkspaceJob("Job2");
Job2.schedule();
WorkspaceJob Job1 = new WorkspaceJob("Job3");
Job3.schedule();
```

I could use:

```
@Subsribe
public replaceJob1(StartJob1Event event) {
    //do what runInWorkspace() of Job1 would have done
    com.something.getStaticEventBus().post(new Job1FinishedEvent());
}


@Subsribe
public replaceJob2(Job1FinishedEvent event) {
    //do what `runInWorkspace()` of Job2 would have done
    com.something.getStaticEventBus().post(new Job2FinishedEvent());
}

@Subsribe
public replaceJob3(Job2FinishedEvent event) {
    //do what `runInWorkspace()` of Job3 would have done
    com.something.getStaticEventBus().post(new Job3FinishedEvent());
}
```

I didn't tried it yet because I simplified the ideas as much as I could and the problem is more complex than that, but I think that the `EventBus` would win in terms of performance over the `WorkspaceJobs`.

Can anyone confirm my idea or tell my why this I shouldn't try this( except for the fact that I must have a good arhitecture of my events)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WorkspaceJob delays resource change events until the job finishes. This prevents components listening for resource changes receiving half completed changes. This may or may not be important to your application.

I can't comment on the Guava code as I don't know anything about it - but note that if your code is long running you must make sure it runs in a background thread (which WorkbenchJob does).

Comment: I would like to add that `getRule` influences if jobs can run in parallel or sequentially. You may want to revise the scheduling rules to see if they are unnecessarily broad.

Comment: If I can make the application responsive and without hanging for example when opening a file, then I think I'll trade a `WorkspaceJob` with a message box that informs the user to wait.